# Hiding/showing fields conditionally w/ checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a conditional fields form from Bootstrap Validator and don't know enough Javascript to make one last thing work.

The form as it is now is [live here](http://pacelink.com/ferris/demo/dynamic4.html)

My problem is both "...a brochure to be sent to me" and "...to arrange a field demonstration" need to open the same address fields, however, if you check "...a brochure sent to me," then check "...to arrange a field demonstration" the fields open and then close again.

How do I create an if statement to verify if the field is already visible and leave it open if it IS, and open it is it's NOT?

Comment: Nevermind, I realized the sillyness of my last comment. If you want to specify the difference between the two you can also update a hidden input value.

Comment: Why don't you just use one label something like: "...a brochure to be sent to me or to arrange a field demonstration"?

Comment: ^ That was exactly what I asked in the comment above before, but it looks like the current arrangement allows the user to have one and not the other. Probably to update a hidden field somewhere that marks which one the user selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks the bootstrapValidator.js file is addressing the checkboxes by class, both of your checkboxes have the name "topic[]" with the same value of "address". You could give each field its unique ID, add in javascript that tells the page to see if either of the checkboxes are checked, and then make the  style display set to block.

Try

```
//HTML - Added ID's to each and the onclick='showblock()'
<input type='checkbox' value='address' name='topic[]' id='address1' onclick='showblock()'></input>
<input type='checkbox' value='address' name='topic[]' id='address2' onclick='showblock()'></input>
<div data-topic="address" style="display: block;" id="addressform">

//JS 
function showblock() {
    if (document.getElementById("address1").checked == true || document.getElementById("address2").checked == true) { 
        document.getElementById("addressform").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("addressform").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

This should work, if it doesn't then the bootstrapValidator is probably overwriting it, you can just change the value of "address" to something other than address.

Comment: It worked! And I actually understood what I was doing, which is always a bonus. Thank you!!!!